# sending email to 2 sharepoint groups using msflow when item created or modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, power-automate, groups, flow

Kindly help me with the steps

1. I need to trigger email for two SharePoint group when item is created or modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint groups don't have an email address. So, you have to use Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action and SharePoint REST API to get the group members and their email addresses

Then you can send email using outlook connector actions.

Follow below article for detailed steps: [How to send an email to a SharePoint group using Power Automate](https://tomriha.com/how-can-i-send-email-to-sharepoint-group-from-power-automate/)

---

**Update**:

Here's the complete flow which should work for you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I want to send to 2 sharepoint groups and i aso came across sending emails for single sharepoint groups but my requirement is i need to send email to members who are part of members sharepoint groups and visitors sharepoint group in msflow

Comment: You have to use  two send an HTTP request actions and then collect email addresses in single array variable using "append to array variable" action. Then you can use `join` function to join email addresses using semicolon.

Comment: I am not sure of 2 send HTTP request actions and i used array variable and passed that to only 1 send HTTP requests and please help me if the below steps works

Comment: I added the steps i am trying and please help me if any issues with my logic and refer above screenshots.Thanks in advance

Comment: Your logic should work. Basically, you are doing same thing (using 2 http request actions).Make sure you are appending correct emails using append to array variable action.

Comment: My append to array variable action is value im getting from apply to each 2 step current item ,is that right ?

Comment: Try flow given in my updated answer. let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help and support